# What happened to the event groups chapter of DOM level 3 specification?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, dom3

In the [2006](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20060413/events.html#Event-groups) version of DOM events level 3 specification there is a chapter "Event groups", but in the current version there is none. What happened to this chapter? Was it intentionally removed? It would be very helpful to have (partially) ordered event handlers list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [was removed in 2006](http://dev.w3.org/cvsweb/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html.diff?r1=1.7&r2=1.8&f=h), but I couldn't find any public record of this decision, neither in [the www-dom mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/), nor in [the webapps wiki](http://www.w3.org/2008/webapps/wiki/). You could ask on the mailing list, perhaps the editors remember the rationale.